# Objective-C selector naming without parameters but with NSError

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the best practice for naming an Objective-C selector that doesn't take parameters but can return an Error?

Example (a method that gets soundtrack data from the web):

```
- (NSData*) soundtrackData:????? error:(NSError**)error;
```

Comment: what you dont understand H2CO3 ?

Comment: I don't understanf your question due to the poor English used. Sorry.

Comment: the focus is the question content, not the grammar or language.. important is to able communicate :)

Comment: I know, but I **really**, **actually** did not understand the question.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has linked to Apple's [Cocoa Coding Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) yet. Maybe you'll find some guidance there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple uses one of two styles in the Cocoa frameworks:

```
- (NSData *)soundtrackData:(NSError **)error;
```

e.g. `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`

```
- (NSData *)soundtrackDataAndReturnError:(NSError **)error;
```

e.g. `-[NSURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:`

It would seem that Apple is favouring the second style for new APIs these days, but either is acceptable. I like the conciseness of the first style, but the second does have a nice advantage that you can search for `error:` to find all methods in your code with error-handling.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
- (NSData*)soundtrackDataWithError:(NSError**)error;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin Ballard.. my doubt is about use this name, because soundtrack not is recovered WITH error.. but when i try recover one i Can GET error.. is more fluent.. anyway, i want to know what the IOS community uses.. :)